# $i^i$ is real number. But $\ln(i^i)=i\cdot \ln(i)=\frac{i}{2}\ln(-1)$. But $\ln(-1)$ is not defined.

Tags: complex-numbers

$i^i$ is a real number. But,
$\ln(i^i)=i\cdot\ln(i)=\frac{i}{2}\ln(-1)$. But $\ln(-1)$ is not defined. So how can $i^i$ be a real number?

Comment: *But $\ln(−1)$ is not defined* - You sure about that ?

Comment: $e^{(2k+1)\pi i}=-1$

Comment: You need to use the complex logarithm. Or use $\log(e^{\frac{- \pi}{2}})$

Comment: $\ln i^i = i$? Really?

Comment: So I'm curious:  How did you manage to define $ln(i)$ in a way that didn't also allow you to define $ln(-1)$?

Comment: @MichaelGaluza: I'm fairly sure that your concern was due to different parsing. Confusingly enough in some parts of the world they use '.' (a period!) as a multiplication sign. Understandably you took it to mean the end of the sentence. I replaced it with $\cdot$ (or `\cdot`). Hopefully easier to parse now :-)

Comment: A way to avoid logarithms is to use $i = e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}$, to get $i^i = e^{\frac{i\pi}{2} \cdot i} = e^{-\pi/2}$. However, using any rotations of $\pi/2$ will lead to multiple answers, which is something I'm not sure why it happens.

Comment: I know how to prove $i^i$ is a real number by taking $i^i={e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}}^i=e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}$, which is a positive number. But what is wrong in my original post?

Comment: Don't mean to be rude but you use complex numbers and you don't know how to define logarithm of negative numbers ?

Comment: $$e^{-\pi/2}=e^{3\pi/2}\ ?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$i^i=\left(\left|i\right|e^{\arg\left(i\right)i}\right)^i=\left(1e^{\arg\left(i\right)i}\right)^i=\left(1e^{\frac{\pi}{2}i}\right)^i=\left(e^{\frac{\pi}{2}i}\right)^i=e^{\frac{\pi}{2}i\cdot i}=e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

---

$$\ln\left(i^i\right)=\ln\left(e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\right)=-\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Because we know that $\ln(-1)=\pi i$

Answer (score -2):

$ln(i) = a$

$e^a = i$

$a = i\pi/2 + 2\pi n$

thus $ln(i) = i\pi/2 + 2\pi n$

$i^i = e^{ln(i)^i} = e^{iln(i)} = e^{-\pi/2}$

Comment: This answers the final question of the OP but ignores the issues he asks to be taken into account. Could you address the actual issues raised?

Comment: @RoryDaulton:  There are no actual  issues raised.  The OP is using some definition of the logarithm according to which $ln(i)$ makes sense and $ln(-1)$ does not.  This must be a highly nonstandard definition, but the OP hasn't told us what it is, so it's quite impossible to answer questions about it.